# Table inside td repeat of tr

Tags: html

I am trying to create a table as per `expected output` but it's not working. You can click on expected output and you can check the desired output

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWKiC.png)

this is the arrangement of table and it's not working

```html
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Example
        </td>
        <td>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Example0
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Example1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: `tr` cannot be a child of `td` so your nested table needs to be wrapped in a `table` tag.  however this does not look like tabular data so you shouldn't be using tables - tables should not be used for layout.  If it is tabular data, you may want to use a `rowspan` instead of a nested table

Comment: Look at these examples on mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#row_and_column_spanning

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Example
    </td>
    <td>
        Example0
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>

    </td>
     <td>
          Example1
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```